# See what causes 500 Internal server error with browser developer tools

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, browser

Im working with Telerik controls in an MVC3 app. Every now and then, i'll get a 500 internal server error or a 404 error. I get the 500 error when i click a tab on my Telerik tabstrip control. What im doing is very very simple. This is my partial view my tab will load:

```
     @model MyModel

      @foreach (var item in Model.Names)
```

When i run this, I get the 500 error. But i can do this and it'll work

```
     @model MyModel
     <div>@Model.Names[0].First</div>
```

I get a 404 when using a grid in a tabstrip as well. I know chrome has some wonderful tools, i just dont know which ones to use. But I dont care which browser, how and what developer tools can i use to find out what's causing these errors?

Comment: Turn off customErrors in web.config and you can see what is causing Http500.

Comment: They're already off, it doesnt help. I get a popup window with the 500 error

Comment: Ok, I do not understand what you mean by "popup", you should see 'nice' yellow error page. Maybe you need to turn off friendly http errors in IE (if you are using it). Or just forget about all that I mentioned and start debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using FireFox firebug instead. It allows you to view the error response from the server. Also @Tomas Voracek in the comment has a good idea to turn off customErrors.

Comment: Ive used Firebug, but I dont know what to do to spot the error. Is there an output window where i can see the server responses?

Comment: Open Firebug (F12) and watch "Console" tab. If it shows the error click on it and select "response" it should have HTML of the error page.

Comment: Im looking in the console window and it shows my error but I have no idea why its an error. I'm gonna repost this question but focusing on the Telerik control. Thanks

Comment: @user1202717 Also on "Net" tab you can see request/response from server.

Comment: I figured it out, with the help of you guys of course. Apparently I needed to wrap my data in DOM elements like a div. Now my data displays fine. Thanks a million

Comment: @bobek: Firebug doesn't help, it shows exactly what I see on screen.

Answer (score 0):

By design you'll find it very difficult to get any server information/errors out of the browser.

there are some server side tools that can help you debug these issues but it depends entirely on your server. Are you using IIS7+?

Comment: Yes, I'm on my development machine so I have access to anything and everything.

Comment: Recommending tools will require better understanding of what your development server is.